# pass id to another screen to display the particular id - product and its details

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have one collection view which have to display only the category name and its image. And i am showing this category name, image by doing some api calling. And also for each category name i will get the customer id for each category name. Here is the full code for that

```
 func apicalling () {

        let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "7adebcbe-18b4-d2a7-2159-2fbcaea27edd"
        ]
        let parameters = [
            "customerID": "1",
            "listType": "2"
        ]
        do {
            let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options :[])
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://example/categoryname.php")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    ///print(error)
                } else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                        {
                            let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                            if(status == 1)
                            {
                                //print("SUCCESS....")
                                if let typeValues = json["categories"] as? [NSDictionary]
                                {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                       // print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")

                                        for item in typeValues
                                        {
                                           // print("INSIDE LISTING ITEMS...")

                                            self.BTdata.append(BTData(json:item))

                                        }

                                        //print(self.BTdata[0].BTNames)


                                         self.collectionView!.reloadData()

                                    })
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    })

                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()
        } catch {
            // print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
        }
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 {
       return BTdata.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

         cell.CatName.text = BTdata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].BTNames

        let imgURL: URL = URL(string: BTdata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].BTImage!)!

        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: imgURL)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil && data != nil)
            {
                func display_image()
                {
                    cell.ProductImg.image = UIImage(data:data!)
                }

              DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: display_image)
            }
        })

        task.resume()

      return cell
  }

 func getIndexPathForSelectedCell() -> IndexPath?
 {
        var indexPath:IndexPath?

        if collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!.count > 0 {
            indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems![0]
        }
     return indexPath
 }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
 {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails"
        {
            if let indexPath = getIndexPathForSelectedCell()
            {
                let ContainerviewController = segue.destination as! DetailVC

                ContainerviewController.BTdata = [BTdata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]]

                print("Printing value on collection click.....")

                print(BTdata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].BTIds)

            }
        }
    }
```

And form my above code you can see that, i have done the segue to another view controller. And i am passing the `ID` to another view controller.In another view controller, i need to display the product items that user select in my first view controller.

In my second view controller, i have done some api to show all product .So the flow is :

1. When user press any category name in my first view controller, it have to go to second view controller and should so the particular product for the selected category name. Here is the code of my second VC :

   **Here i am getting the id from my first vc that user clicked any category name :**

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.BTypeId = BTdata[0].BTIds
       Allproductapicalling ()
   }

   func Allproductapicalling () {

       let headers = [
           "content-type": "application/json",
           "cache-control": "no-cache",
           "postman-token": "c98d0000-637b-1efc-8f93-f9e277ffefcd"
       ]
       let parameters = [
           "customerID": "1",
           "listType": "1"
       ]

       do {
           let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options :[])
           let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://exp.php")! as URL,
                                             cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
           request.httpBody = postData

           let session = URLSession.shared
           let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
               if (error != nil) {
                   ///print(error)
               } else {

                   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                       if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                       {
                           let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                           if(status == 1)
                           {
                               print("SUCCESS....")

                               if let typeValues = json["products"] as? [NSDictionary]
                               {
                                   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                       print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")

                                        for item in typeValues {

                                           let bId = item.value(forKey: "categoryID") as! String

                                           if(bId == self.BTypeId) {

                                              self.Productdata.append(ProductData(json:item))

                                           }
                                       }

                                   })

                                   //print("Product Name : ", self.Productdata[0].proName)
                               }

                           }

                       }
                   })

               }
           })

           dataTask.resume()



       } catch {
           // print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
       }
   }
   ```

My problem is in this line from above api calling code :

```
if let typeValues = json["products"] as? [NSDictionary]
{
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                for item in typeValues {
                   let bId = item.value(forKey: "categoryID") as! String
                         if(bId == self.BTypeId) {
                                self.Productdata.append(ProductData(json:item))
                         }
                       }

                   })
```

i am getting the selected category id from my first VC, and i am comparing with the all product api calling category id. And i need to display that particular product alone.How to do that ??

```
if(bId == self.BTypeId)
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: please tell me that self.BTypeId is string ?

Comment: Yes , in that only i am passing the category id of my first vc selected category name

Comment: put break point on this condition and check that value both are same or different one

Comment: i did like this `if(bId == self.BTypeId) {  print("6 product are there.....")  }`. I got the print statement

Comment: But when i do append and to see the product values. I am not getting the particular product for the selected category

Comment: just make one print statement after append your self.productdata

Comment: If its equal, `self.Productdata.append(ProductData(json:item))`. I did like this

Comment: `6 product are there.....` it printing for 6 times. But not able to see the self.productdata

Comment: print this statement in if condition

Comment: i did, its not showing the data, and also the print statement

Comment: self.Productdata.append(item) try this statement and check it

Comment: for that item its showing unresolved identifier

Comment: i did like this ` print(self.Productdata.append(ProductData(json:item)))` It showing {}

Comment: how ? because you have item in your for loop  then how should it unresolver identifier ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126313/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-mack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
   for item in typeValues {
       let bId = item.value(forKey: "categoryID") as! String
       if(bId as? String == self.BTypeId) {
               print("Hurray sathish......")
               self.Productdata.append(ProductData(json:item))

               // print(self.Productdata.append(bId))

        }
     }
     self.Collectionview.delegate = self
     self.Collectionview.dataSource = self
     self.Collectionview.reloadData()
 })

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionviewcell

        cell.DetailProductName.text = Productdata[indexPath.row].proDescription

        let imgURL: URL = URL(string: Productdata[indexPath.row].proImage!)!

        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: imgURL)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil && data != nil)
            {
                func display_image()
                {
                    cell.DetailImage.image = UIImage(data:data!)
                }


                DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: display_image)
            }
        })

        task.resume()


        return cell
    }
```

Your Output :

[image]

Your problem solve approve answer and give up vote thank you. 
Happy Coding.